# Access my Firefox plugin under root

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, npapi, firebreath

i recently build a Firefox plugin that scans fingerprint using FireBreath framework. the problem is when i run the test on the plugin in normal mode, the plugin run perfectly but doesn't allow me to use my usb scanner as i need root access . Now , when i start Firefox as root, i can't find the plugin among the plugins list on Firefox . i finally tried to copy my plugin file "plg.so" to /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/ . that added my plugin to the list on Firefox but when i try to access it , Firefox get freeze . thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't use linux enough to know this one; what you're looking for is how to install a npapi plugin in firefox on linux as root.  However, what you tried is what I would expect to work, so I don't know.  I added the npapi tag, maybe someone else will know.

Answer (score 0):

The different plugin install locations are document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#How_Gecko_Finds_Plug-ins).
If you install them per-user (`~/.mozilla/plugins`), you need to install them for every user you want to use them as (i.e. also install them for root), although you can also install them globally as you found out.

For the freezing, it's impossible to tell what the problem is without more information.
I recommend to [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Plug-ins&cc=georg.fritzsche@gmail.com) with a [stack trace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_get_a_stacktrace_for_a_bug_report) (either crash report id if you can get it to crash while frozen or manually using the alternative methods).